# Codeigniter 3 + multilingual + https

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, https

I have a website with both english and french
My htaccess rules works perfectly, but I would like to force https.

I have been trying few examples here and there, but I think because I am using a bilingual system, it doesn't work as expected.

Here is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
# RewriteRule ^(app(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.eot|\.ttf|\.svg|\.woff|\.woff2|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]



</IfModule>
```

Comment: Show the code you tried for https!

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#add this one as first rule
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
# RewriteRule ^(app(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.eot|\.ttf|\.svg|\.woff|\.woff2|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]



</IfModule>

# Note: It’s also recommended to enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)
# on your HTTPS website to help prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.
# See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you Tpojka,

The message I have now is 

Found

The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Have you enabled SSL on server?

Comment: The Dns goes through cloudflare, so normaly yes

Comment: it says "SSL: Flexible"

Comment: Try without last `if module` block.

Comment: I have the same message 302 : (